# Resharper c++ does not display squiggles for error or warning

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I'm using Resharper C++ 2022.3 on VS2022.

[Example in Vanilla VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoRoZ.png)

When typing inappropriately, In vanilla VS, display redline squiggle as above.

[Example in Reshaper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHq4y.png)

but when using Resharper, don't display squiggle as above.

so, I want to see redline for error like vanilla while using resharper.

How can i solve this problem?

`Tools` > `Text Editor` > `C/C++` > `Advanced` > `"Disable Error Reporting"` is False,

and Resharper option > `Editor` > `Visual Studio Features` > `"Hide Visual Studio squiggles"` is unchecked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When "Hide Visual Studio squiggles" is unchecked, VS error squiggles should be shown even when ReSharper is running. There's [a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-489709) in the 2022.3 release however which causes R# to hide VS squiggles. Hopefully it should be fixed soon, you can vote for the issue to subscribe for notifications.

Regarding R# not showing an error in your code, that's another issue which is already fixed internally and the fix will be available in R# 2023.1.

Comment: I can confirm that this issue is not limited to C++ projects. It is strange that JetBrains has not made the fix available sooner, to date, since it is blocking one of the most basic yet important features of Visual Studio.

Version 2023.1 is still not available.